# Calculate data in Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, pivot, date-arithmetic

I have the following SQL table with 4 columns.

Table Name: tblTimeTransaction

Columns: EmployeeNumber, TransactionDate, CodeType, TimeShowninSeconds

CodeType has values : REG, OT1, OT2, OT3 respectively

I want it to show like this using pivot using 15 days incrementals starting from Jan 1 2020 onwards:

```
Employee Number | Effective Date        | REG   | OT1 | OT2     | OT3
E12345      | Between 10-1 till 10-15   | 200   | 100 | 50      | 45 
E15000      | Between 10-1 till 10-15   | 400   | 600 | 903     | 49
E12345      | Between 10-15 till 10-31  | 200   | 100 | 50      | 45 
E15000      | Between 10-15 till 10-31  | 400   | 600 | 903     | 49
E12346      | Between 11-1 till 11-15   | 4200  | 100 | 50      | 45 
E15660      | Between 11-1 till 11-15   | 1200  | 600 | 6903    | 49
```

My SQL Code so far:

```
SELECT 
    Employee Number, 
    [TransactionDate] as [Effective Date], 
    [REG], 
    [OT1],
    [OT2],
    [OT3] 
    
FROM 
       ( SELECT Employee Number, TransactionDate, CodeType, TimeInSeconds
         FROM [tblTimetransaction] 
       ) ps
PIVOT
       ( SUM (TimeInSeconds)
         FOR CodeType IN ( [REG], [OT1], [OT2], [OT3])
       ) AS pvt
where TransactionDate between '2020-01-01' and '2020-12-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

*If* I follow you correctly, you can truncate the `effective_date` to either the 1st of 15th of the month depending on their day of the month, then use conditional aggregation to compute the total `time_in_seconds` for each `code_type`:

```
select employee_number,
    datefromparts(year(effective_date), month(effective_date), case when day(effective_date) < 15 then 1 else 15 end) as dt,
    sum(case when code_type = 'REG' then time_in_seconds else 0 end) as reg,
    sum(case when code_type = 'OT1' then time_in_seconds else 0 end) as ot1,
    sum(case when code_type = 'OT2' then time_in_seconds else 0 end) as ot2,
    sum(case when code_type = 'OT3' then time_in_seconds else 0 end) as ot3
from tblTimetransaction
where effective_date >= '20200101' and effective_date < '20210101'
group by employee_number, 
    datefromparts(year(effective_date), month(effective_date), case when day(effective_date) < 15 then 1 else 15 end)
```